# Which language(s) have the most complete SDK(s) for interacting with AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sdk

There are [AWS SDKs for several different languages](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/#sdk): C++, Go, Java, .NET, Node.js, PHP, Python and Ruby.

It appears that some of these SDKs support more features of AWS than others (for example, [CloudFront only seems to be supported by](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/APIReference/AWSLibraries.html) Java, .NET, PHP, Python and Ruby). Which language(s) have the most complete SDK(s) for interacting with AWS?

Are some of the SDKs more "official" than others?

Comment: The SDK provide a wrapper onto the REST APIs that AWS provides.  If the API changes then the SDK for all the different languages has to as well.  As I understand it no language is favoured over any other, they just seem to depend on good communications, the individual SDK projects being easy to change and the project teams being on the ball.  You are quite right that there are sometimes things missing from SDKs that are present in the AWS REST API

Answer (score 2):

You pointed out CloudFront is only supported by these: Java, .NET, PHP, Python and Ruby.

From my reading of developer guides, those seem to be the most common languages with examples present. I would say that Java, PHP, and Python are the most commonly shown and have the strongest community.

Additionally, Java, Python, and Node are the only languages currently supported by Lambda, and they all come bundled with the SDK by default. Since Lambda originally supported only Node, I'm guessing Java and Python were the two most requested/used languages.

So, Java or Python are probably the most active and supported, but all of the SDKs are "official".

Comment: Seems like every other devops job posting is asking for knowledge of python, and after looking at the SDK docs, I think Python has the most easy to understand/use out of all AWS sdks, and I do believe there is a reason why most devops person chooses python. The masses are not going to pick the harder option to do their work if something easier presents.